# no key repeat in Xquartz (x11)

Tags: macos, terminal, x11, xquartz

I don't think I've used x11 since switching to Mountain Lion (and thus Xquartz).  I recently tried to use it and my key repeat isn't working.  When I press a key, it inserts the corresponding character once, then a second time after (very roughly) a quarter second, then never repeats again.  I've tried `xset r` and `xset r on` from both my x11 terminal, and normal Terminal.app --- neither has any effect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [@jaykru on SuperUser.SO (https://superuser.com/a/414513/152522)](https://superuser.com/a/414513/152522):

> Did some more searching and discovered in recent updates the key
>   repeat rate for x in OS X is set at some odd value. Anyway, to whoever
>   else may have this issue, run this in your shell:
>
> ```
>     xset r rate <milliseconds_before_repeat> <repeats_per_second>
> ```
>
> Or just `xset r rate` to reset the keyboard repeat rate to default X
>   settings (i.e: something sane.)

Comment: i can't get xinitrc to not choke on xset's.

Comment: Where should I put this setting?

Comment: @mcb you run it in the terminal

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix: Every time? Is there no way to have this set automatically?

Comment: @mcb That sets the default value.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix: Really? It does not stay the same for me when I close XQuartz.app.